# Is there an alternative Android emulator for Visual Studio on Windows 10 Home

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When using Visual Studio 2015 to develop c++ for Android the emulator only works if you are running a Pro version of Windows, for those using Visual Studio Community who are probably also running on a Home version of windows (like me) the Emulator will not work.

Is there an alternative available that can integrate with the VS debugger?

*** Edit
I have been looking at this list [Android emulators](https://www.maketecheasier.com/android-desktop-emulator/)  although this seems to be aimed at android gaming on PC rather than App development.  So was wondering if anyone had managed to integrate one of these with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Both the below options come with the caveat that I have not used either.

**[Xamarin Android Player](https://xamarin.com/android-player)**

Apparently Xamarin had issues with the default Android Emulator. Primarily that it was slow, and clunky, and they were getting a lot of complaints about it from Xamarin users (despite it not being their product/fault).

They decided to create their own emulator to get around this, and it can be found [here](https://xamarin.com/android-player).

It should be noted that (at time of writing) this is still in Preview by the looks of things. So bugs may be present.

From what I can see on the download page, it doesn't appear like you need Xamarin to actually use it. In any case, it's worth a shot.

**[GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)**

Another option is GenyMotion. There is a free version for personal use only (with limited functionality), or a paid option that provides more capability.

Comment: Thanks, this will be worth keeping an eye on. However at the moment it seems to be for signed-up customers only, or there is a $25/month fee for a 'preview' product :-/ so I've decided not to go for it just yet.

Comment: The $25pcm cost is for Xamarin, rather than just the XAP. I was able to download and install the XAP without logging in, or it asking for license details.

Comment: The site says its for customers with Xamarin.Android trials or subscriptions, have you been able to run it without Xamarin?

Comment: I've installed it, but it won't run.  Says it can't find VirtuaBox even though that installed and is running fine on my pc.  So not sure if its a config problem or a license problem with a misleading error message...

Comment: I certainly don't have any other Xamarin product installed, and didnt need to sign in to download or install it. You may need a reboot to get it running though, not sure.

Comment: :-) I was in the middle of a reboot when you posted your comment.  Yes, that was it, I only seem to have access to Nexus devices but they seem to work, so I will now see if I can integrate it with VS, which their site suggests I can.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is going to work, whether it is VS Community or that I'm running on Windows Home, but the options don't appear under the tools menu for attaching the emulator

Comment: @AntG `Run as Administrator` if player can't find the dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Android player link has changed to here: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/

I had problems starting the android VMs, even after restarting the host. There seems to be some incompatibilities between Windows 10 Home and Virtualbox 5.0.4 that Android player installs. Installing Virtuallbox 5.1.2 after installing Android player seems to have resolved this.

EDIT: <strike>I haven't had a chance to test integration with Visual Studio yet.</strike>

Everything seems to be working as expected within Visual Studio. Both of the VM devices I created in Android Player are visible in the drop down of the run menu. Visual Studio will start the selected VM when I debug the default blank android app.

The only hiccup is that Visual Studio doesn't wait long enough for the emulator to start before attempting to deploy the app. So I have to start the run again or remember to start the VM from Android Player before debugging.

Comment: This is not working anymore. The repo was deleted and archived.